# javascript can't find iframe after reload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe

I'm not asking for a solution, because I solved the problem. This is more of a 'why did it happen'? Understanding is at the root of everything, and I can't figure out why it happened.

I have a web page with two layered div's (Div 1 and Div 2).
Div1 displays a button, when clicked Div 2 appears, containing a form and an iframe (named 'myframe').
When the user clicks 'cancel' in Div 2, Div 2 is emptied and it disappears, showing Div 1 again.
Everything is loaded using Ajax and PHP.

My problem:
The first time I click the button in Div 1, everything displays fine and - most important - I can acces the iframe with javascript.

Both

```
var b=window.frames['myframe']
and 
var b=window.frames[0]
```

result in alert(b.name) displaying 'myframe'.

The strange thing is however when I cancel Div 2 (empty it and hiding it) and then pressing the button in Div 1 again, using exactly the same code, gives me 'NULL' in javascript when referring to the iframe.
I've checked the DOM, Div 2 is really empty after cancelling and the iframe is there the second time, displaying it's contents correctly, so why isn't javascript picking it up? I've tried waiting for a few minutes before hitting the button again, loading another page in Div 2 first, but it didn't work.

My solution is adding the time to the iframe-name, thus giving it a unique name everytime it loads. This works fine, now javascript can acces the iframe even after a 'cancel'.

My question is: why, when using a static name, can't js find the iframe the second time?

the contents of div 2 is:

```
//THE FORM
<form id="myform" name="myform" class="myform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" onsubmit="" onkeypress="return keyCheck(event)">
// some form stuff
</form>
<iframe src='imbo/php/system_fotohidden.php' id='myframe' name='myframe'></iframe>
```

and the javascript:

```
function click(){
    var b=window.frames['myframe'];
    alert(b.name);
    }
```

**[EDIT]**
Maybe to clarify what I'm doing with the div's:

1. click button 'loadform' in Div 1
2. Ajax loads a page with Form and Iframe in Div 2 (it all display's nice)
3. acces the Iframe in div 2 with JS => JS finds the Iframe and pops up it's name
4. cancel the form: JS => div2.innerHTML='' and div2.style.display='none'
5. click button 'loadform' in Div 1
6. Ajax loads the exact same page with Form and Iframe in Div 2 (it still display's nice)
7. acces the Iframe in div 2 with JS => JS gives NULL instead of the Iframe-name

Comment: What do you mean "empty [Div2]"? This might be the clue. Could you paste some code?

Comment: in javascript: div2.innerHTML="";

Comment: I guess you are deleting the IFRAME, so it has no name, because it does not exist anymore. To hide it you can use `DIV.style.visibility='hidden';`

Comment: I need Div2 for showing other pages as well, so just hiding isn't an option.
the iframe DOES exist after loading the form-page in Div2 a second time. I can see it in the DOM. It displays fine with all the content in it. Only javascript can't find it anymore.

Comment: I don't agree, if you set innerHTML to '' you should delete all its children. But now I'm not sure. Do you have a working example of it?

Comment: Please take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/ptFwE/

Comment: Did you try giving it a unique id and access it with `document.getElementById`? `window.frames` is a quite old fashioned way.

Comment: @Voitcus: You are right, setting innerHTML to '' deletes al the children of Div 2. But I'm reloading it (so Div 2 gets it's contents back, with the iframe) and then it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Joshua: That was my solution, giving it a unique ID everytime I reload it and that works (see my question). But still don't know why JS can't find it when reloaded with a static Id and Name

Answer (score 0):

By setting the element `innerHTML` property to "" you delete all of its children, so they no longer exist. You can't refer to them, neither by name nor by `document.frames`, nor anything else.

To hide `DIV` element you can use `DIV.style.visibility='hidden';`.

Here is an example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ptFwE/1/; you can see that `childNodes` property of the `div` says there are no children in the `DIV` after setting `innerHTML` to the empty string.

If you need this div for other purposes consider setting `visibility` of IFRAME to `hidden` only or use another DIV.

Comment: I know it's deleting the children. But I reload the page in the div, and that's when JS can't find the iframe anymore.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you more. It can be some error in Ajax code, maybe the page is not EXACTLY the same. If it is however correct, the problem might be that you cannot delete an object and create 2nd with the same name, but it's only my assumption, in which I don't believe. If you see this IFRAME it is in your DOM so even if it has no name or wrong name, you should have been able to access it by `document.frames`. You can also try to test it with another browser, if it is a DOM problem.

Comment: Thnx anyway. I found a solution, so it works fine. Just was curious what could have happened.